# Converting files in a specific folder specified by a relative path

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.4, error-000732, file-path

I am writing a script to automate the process of converting a group of rasters, the fact is that I need to set a relative path, it will be used on different pc. But there is always an error [error-000732], how to solve this problem?
The code that I have now
error stack:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\projects\prototype\Конвертация.py", line 15, in <module>
    arcpy.RasterToOtherFormat_conversion("input_files", "output", "TIFF")
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.4\ArcPy\arcpy\conversion.py", line 2658, in RasterToOtherFormat
    raise e
ExecuteError: РќРµ СѓРґР°РµС‚СЃСЏ РІС‹РїРѕР»РЅРёС‚СЊ. РџР°СЂР°РјРµС‚СЂС‹ РЅРµ РєРѕСЂСЂРµРєС‚РЅС‹.
ERROR 000732: Input Rasters: РќР°Р±РѕСЂ РґР°РЅРЅС‹С… input_files РЅРµ СЃСѓС‰РµСЃС‚РІСѓРµС‚ РёР»Рё РЅРµ РїРѕРґРґРµСЂР¶РёРІР°РµС‚СЃСЏ
РќРµ СѓРґР°Р»РѕСЃСЊ РІС‹РїРѕР»РЅРёС‚СЊ (RasterToOtherFormat).
```

> > > 

```
import os
import glob
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
inpath = r".\\data\\ice\\input"
env.workspace = os.path.realpath(inpath)
data_rasters = arcpy.ListRasters("", "BIL")
for raster in data_rasters:
    desc = arcpy.Describe(raster)
    path = desc.path
    input_files = str(path) + "/" + raster
    arcpy.RasterToOtherFormat_conversion("input_files", "output", "TIFF")
```

Comment: Why do you define input_files, you never use it?

Comment: Please post the entire error stack.

Comment: Why are you appending `raster` (an object) to the path of `raster` wit a `+` in `input_files = ...` ?  What's that last line (`RasterToOtherFormat_conversion`) supposed to convert - what is `"listf"`?

Answer (score 1):

You're passing a string into the RasterToOtherFormat_conversion tool. Take `input_files` and `output` out of quotes. You should also declare an output folder. I would change your code to something like this:

```
import os
import glob
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
inpath = r".\\data\\ice\\input"
env.workspace = os.path.realpath(inpath)
output = r"C:\output" #Change this to whatever path you want 
data_rasters = arcpy.ListRasters("", "BIL")
for raster in data_rasters:
    desc = arcpy.Describe(raster)
    path = desc.path
    input_file = str(path) + "/" + raster
    arcpy.RasterToOtherFormat_conversion(input_file, output, "TIFF")
```

It should be noted that the documentation for [the tool](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/conversion-toolbox/raster-to-other-format-multiple-.htm) also accepts a list of rasters. So you could just have the following without a for loop:

```
arcpy.RasterToOtherFormat_conversion(data_rasters, output, "TIFF")
```